# mysqli prepare - only works when not a function?

Tags: php, parameters, mysqli

That one always returns a false bool:

```
<?php
function check($username, $db_conx) {
    $sql = 'SELECT User_ID FROM tbl_user WHERE Username=?';
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $ret= $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $db_conx->close();
    $ret = $ret->fetch_row();
    return $ret;
}

$usr = "root";
$res = check($u,$db_conx);
echo var_dump($res);
echo $a[0];
?>
```

I don't get it, they are pretty equal - so what's the error?

That one returns what I expected:

```
<?php
$usr = 'root';
$sql = "SELECT User_ID FROM tbl_user WHERE Username=?";
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $usr);
$stmt->execute();
$ret = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
$db_conx->close();

$ret = $ret->fetch_row();
echo var_dump($ret);
echo $ret[0];
?>
```

I want to recycle it over and over again with the function, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible to set & execute the parameters in a function or have I just made a stupid mistake?

Comment: You are sure it works outside the function? I would think that calling `$db_conx->close()` in either case would break it.  Don't close your database connection. PHP will do that for you later, and it looks like you've closed it before fetching your row.

Comment: Oh, there it is. Your variable is `$usr = 'root';`, not `$u` as passed  to the function `$res = check($u,$db_conx);`

Comment: Turn on `display_errors` and crank up `error_reporting`, always in development. You should see a notice  about an undefined variable `$u`.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Ugh, that happened when I simplified it and forgot to change the $u to $usr. It still is not working. When I comment out the connection close it's still broken.

Comment: Remove the `$db_conx->close()`. Turn up error_reporting, and see what's going on.  Debug MySQLi with statements like `if (!$stmt) echo $db_conx->error;` after calling `prepare()`.  (you did connect to establish `$db_conx` in code we don't see, right?)

Comment: "*that happened when I simplified it"* - if you **actually** want help with your problem, don't **ever** do this

Comment: Solved.
I've executed the plain script before the function wich has closed the db_conx, ofc it couldnt query then^^